# Can puppet workflow stop when there is an error in manifest?

Tags: puppet

I am looking out options for making my puppet run stop as in when I see some failure in some check inside a manifest.

When I execute puppet agent -t on the node, if there is some error in manifest, it should stop the execution rather than proceeding with the remaining manifest.

I tried the command "fail", if the file cannot be found on the node, but I got this error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call
```

I was trying something similar below, if the file exist then notify I am present else fail and stop the execution

```
$file = "/tmp/file"
exec { "chk_${file}_exist":
  command => "true",
  path    =>  ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin", "/bin"],
  onlyif  => "test -f ${file}"
}
-> if !(Exec["chk_${file}_exist"]) {
      fail('I am failing')
        }
else {
      notify { 'I am present  ":}
}
```

Comment: How is the effect of the `fail` function different from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: More generally, are you confusing catalog *building* (on the master, from manifests, data, and facts) with catalog *application* (on the client)?

Comment: Can you please be more specific ?I  was trying to execute the command from a node (testing ) I wanted an output on the console saying "I am failing " instead of the error "Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, *"

Comment: Ok, there seems to be a terminology issue here.  If there is an error *in a manifest* then catalog compilation fails. In a master / agent setup that happens on the master, with the result being just such an error message as you receive.  You seem instead want a way to halt *catalog application* immediately upon failure of any resource.

Comment: Ok i think i understand you .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no general-purpose mechanism in Puppet to make catalog application abort completely upon failure of a single resource, though such a feature [has been requested before](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/3933).  One generally approaches such a question with a bit more precision, via one facet or another of [resource relationships](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_relationships.html).

If you have one resource whose correct application depends on another specific resource having successfully been applied first, then you describe that to Puppet by declaring a relationship between the two, using either one of the chaining operators or one of the resource metaparameters designated for that purpose (`before`, `require`, `notify`, `subscribe`).  That will ensure both the relative order of application of those resources, and that no attempt is made to apply the dependent one if applying the dependency fails.  You can apply that concept to *groups* of resources by establishing relationships with classes or defined-type instances on one or both sides, or even by bringing [run stages](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_run_stages.html) to bear.

There is currently no way, however, to make catalog application overall to halt immediately upon resource failure when there remain resources that are eligible to be applied.

Comment: Hi John,Thanks for the comment,quite informative  .I understand that we can use this "declaring a relationship" but the point is puppet doesnt stop execution if the dependancy has failures ,it just skips with the message "Notice: /Stage[main]/.......: Dependency Exec[...]   has failures: true  Warning: /Stage[main]/.......:Skipping because of failed dependencies and then continues with remaining

Comment: Yes, @user3355927, that's what I already said.  What I led with, in fact: "To the best of my knowledge, there is no general-purpose mechanism in Puppet to make catalog application abort completely upon failure of a single resource."

Comment: Thank you so much John .Marking your answer as correct :)